# findstr multiple search string and print each occurrence only the first line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

for example i have text file with content

```
superman
batman
hello world
sport cars
hello world2
jackie chan
flower
supermom
hello world3
clock
fried chicken
microsoft
flower boy
flash dance
flower girl
flowerwoman
sun flower
what the hello
```

i want to create a batch file using findstr with multiple search string, for example: hello and flower, but i want to print only the first occurence each, in other words, it will skip the first search string and move on to search the next string. so the result will be like this:

```
hello world
flower
hello world3
flower boy
what the hello
```

is this possible? i can print all the occurence found in multiple files to output.txt with this code

```
@echo off
>"output.txt" (
  for %%F in (*.txt) do (
    findstr /c:"hello" /c:"flower" "%%F"
    (echo()
  )
)
findstr . "output.txt" >"output.txt.new"
move /y "output.txt.new" "output.txt" >nul
type output.txt
```

Comment: As I understand the question the output should only have two lines: `hello world` and `flower`, so why are there 5?

Comment: sorry if the title makes you misunderstood, i've changed the title. it's not literally once, but once for every multiple occurences, which is the first line only. so, if want it to find "X" and "Z" from text file contains "A,B,X,F,X,Z,Z,Z,S,Z,B,X,R,X,P,X,D,Z,B,Z" the result wouldnt be "X,Z" nor "X,X,Z,Z,Z,Z" nor "X,X,Z,Z,Z,Z,X,X,X,Z,Z", what i expect is "X,Z,X,Z"

Comment: Does order matter?  So,  if you want it to find `Z` and `X`, then expected output should be `Z,X,Z` **or** the same as if searching for `X` and `Z`, i.e. `X,Z,X,Z`?

Comment: You have not put enough thought into the requirements, and/or you have not described the requirements adequately. For example, what do you expect if one string has both search words, like `hello flower boy`?

Comment: @dbenham thank you for the input, because in my case its not going to happen, so people who see this question don't need to think about it. but if you need to know, i would expect it to appear too, because the rule still appy to it, "flower" found, skip, find "hello", "hello" found in those words ("hello flower boy"), or the opposite.

Comment: @JosefZ if you mean by the order of the search string, it doesnt matter. which one found first, then i need it to be printed. but the order of the line does matter. i mean it shouldnt print all occurences of "x" first, then after that all occurrences of "z".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "word[0]=hello"
set "word[1]=flower"
set "lastFind="

>"output.tmp" (
   for %%F in (*.txt) do (
      for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /c:"%word[0]%" /c:"%word[1]%" "%%F"') do (
         set "line=%%a"
         if not defined lastFind (
            if "!line:%word[0]%=!" equ "!line!" (set lastFind=0) else set lastFind=1
         )
         for %%b in (!lastFind!) do for /F %%c in ("!word[%%b]!") do if "!line:%%c=!" equ "!line!" (
            echo !line!
            set /A "lastFind=(lastFind+1)%%2"
         )
      )
      rem Activate next line to restart the seek in each file
      REM set "lastFind="
   )
)
ren output.tmp output.txt
type output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "MATCH1=hello"
set "MATCH2=flower"

>"output.txt" (
  for %%F in (*.txt) do if not %%~nxF==output.txt (
    set matchIndex=0
    set expectedMatch=%MATCH1%
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /c:"%MATCH1%" /c:"%MATCH2%" "%%F"') do (
        echo %%a | find "!expectedMatch!" >nul
        if !matchIndex!==0 (
            set matchIndex=1
            if errorlevel 1 set matchIndex=2 & ver>nul
        )
        if not errorlevel 1 (
            echo %%a
            set /a matchIndex=!matchIndex! %% 2 + 1
            call set "expectedMatch=%%MATCH!matchIndex!%%"
        )
    )
  )
)
type output.txt
pause
```

Currently the expected match index is reset to the first search string each new *.txt file, so in case you want a continuous alteration of strings between files simply move `set matchIndex=1` before the first loop.

Comment: thanks for the answer but when i tried yours, the result is still the same as my old batch, which prints all occurences.

Comment: Your code expects that the first match in the file be "hello". If the first match is "flower", your method fail.

Comment: @Aacini, thank you. I've updated the code for the sake of history.